# Trouble sending AJAX GET request to mongodb

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently trying to display data from a mongodb collection on the browser using nodejs and express and am having a very tough time with it. Here is the call itself on the clientside.

```
document.onload= $(function (e) {
var i = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/viewdata",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    success: function (responseData, status) {
       //code doing things with the data
    }
```

Here is whats going on in node.

```
app.post('/viewdata', function(req, res){
    tweets.find({}, function (err, doc) {
        res.render('../../views/view.html', doc);   
    });
});
```

The call is returning "200 OK". I was able to view the data from mongo on the console so I know the data is there, I am not sure how to get to it and display it on the browser though. Thanks for the help

Comment: Long shot, but try "res.render('view.html', doc);"  (without the relative path)

Comment: The relative path is correct, I did not set the view so it is going from the current file location. I have other portions of the code where that works, so I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: You say you get a "200 OK". When you console.log(responseData), do you get the data you want?

Comment: It never reaches the success function, it fails to make the request so it goes to my failure function handles the error by reporting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer to this question, the problem is that I am trying to get data from the server in a post request. I made a separate GET request below the POST request and sent the data to the view. You can now use an ajax get request and use the data on the client-side.

```
app.get('/viewdata', function(req, res){
 tweets.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
    /*console.log(items);*/
    res.send(items);
    });
});
```

And on the clientside:

```
$.get("/viewdata", function(data) {
/*do stuff with the data*/
}
```